Is this possible to autogenerate SFDX Url token after sandbox refresh and set it in Jenkins as secret automatically?
Every time I refresh a sandbox, I need to login into it, grant access to SFDX and then generate the new SFDX Auth URL token from sfdx and then copy it and paste into Jenkins as a secret.
I wonder if this is possible to autogenerate SFDX Url token after sandbox refresh and set it in Jenkins as secret automatically?

Potentially I could call some webhook in Jenkins with sandbox name from SandboxPostCopy class.
Inside Jenkins hook I could execute UI automation based on puppeteer or some other UI automation library and then make it execute
./auth.sh $sandboxName script
sf auth web login -a $1 -r https://test.salesforce.com
and paste the username built dynamically and password set as Jenkins secret using UI automation and then click approve using UI automation script.
After that, I could execute orgd.sh $sandboxName script
sf org display -o $1 --json --verbose > ~/$1.json
to generate the file and then explore Jenkins API to set the file as a secret.
